# spring data jpa datasource connect to Oracle DB with trust store password

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ssl-certificate, datasource, dbconnection

new spring boot application using spring data jpa and we need to connect oracle DB without password set in `spring.datasource.password` instead need to use connectionProperties with javax.net.ssl.truststore file and javax.net.ssl.truststorePassword.

please help me how we can go with approach to connect DB with spring data jpa?

existing application used same without DB password but used certificate to connect DB in jdbc template.

`spring.datasource.url`
`spring.datasource.driverClassName`
`spring.datasource.username`
// No DB password here but we need to use certificates

`javax.net.ssl.truststore = load cert file from file path`
`javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType`
`javax.net.ssl.truststorePassword = load encrypted cert password from file path`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the details in the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc-tlsv12-jks-or-oracle-wallets-122-and-lower)? You do need the password along with the certificate. Certificate is to enable stronger security with SSL but not to eliminate database password.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave oracle bound to localhost and use SSH tunnel on spring to connect to it.
On the Oracle server use key to connect ssh instead of password.

Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766760/4903232